# Run sed command in perl script

Tags: sed, perl

I am unable to invoke the sed command from the perl script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
my $cmd = ('sed 's/...........//;s/............$//' a_file.txt >> a_newfile.txt');
  system($cmd);
```

Below is the error:

```
String found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 2, near "s/............$//' a_file.txt >> a_newfile.txt'"
syntax error at ./test.pl line 2, near "'sed 's/...........//"
syntax error at ./test.pl line 2, near "s/............$//' a_file.txt >> a_newfile.txt'"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I need to remove the `<shortname>u********.com</shortname>` in the file and save the output in a new file. Which commands do I need to run?

Comment: Why do you want to run `sed` from `perl`?

Comment: You're trying to embed single quotes in a single quoted string, but you haven't done anything to escape them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ignoring for now the fact that `perl` can do better anything that `sed` can do, here to quote the shell command line to pass to  `system()`, best would be to use the `q{...}` type of quotes:

```
my $cmd = q{sed 's/...........//;s/............$//' a_file.txt >> a_newfile.txt};
```

(assuming the `...` part doesn't contain unbalanced `{`/`}`, if it does, you can use `q@...@`, `q[...]`, `q(...)`...).

Because you do want a shell to interpret that command line (for the `>>` redirection), you want `$cmd` to be a scalar, not array (anyway arrays are named `@cmd`, not `$cmd`).

For `perl` to run the `sed` command by itself, that is without invoking a shell, you'd do:

```
my @cmd = ('sed', q{s/...........//;s/............$//}, 'a_file.txt');
system(@cmd);
```

But then, you'd need to do the stdout redirection in `perl` beforehand. Like:

```
open STDOUT, '>>', 'a_newfile.txt' or die "open: $!"
```

To do the whole thing in perl instead:

```
open my $in, '<', 'a_file.txt' || die "open a_file: $!";
open my $out, '>>', 'a_newfile.txt' || die "open a_newfile: $!";

while (<$in>) {
  s/...........//;s/............$//;
  print $out $_;
}
close $in;
close $out;
```